# How do I refactor this code with if/else for Update/Delete event and the class is injected using Guice

Tags: java, design-patterns, guice

I'm trying to refactor one of the classes we have which is very long. The class is a listener which has only two events `Update` and `Delete`. We started with just this

```java
public class DocumentListener implements Listener
{
    @Inject
    public DocumentListener(// a bunch of injected parameters) {

    }

    public void receive(Event event)
    {
        Phase phaseWhenReceived = phase_;
        if (event instanceof UpdateEvent) {
            // do update
        } else if (event instanceof EntityDeleteEvent) {
            // do delete
        } else if (event instanceof PhaseEvent) {
            // do nothing for now.
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("Received unknown event type : " + event.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

The class grew to be over 2000 lines long which naturally we want to have two classes; Update and Delete. However, the class is binded with Guice like this.

```java
bind(DocumentListener.class).in(SINGLETON);
```

I started changing the class to be `abstract` class and then created `Update` and `Delete` classes to extract the behaviors.

But if I do this

```java
public abstract DocumentListener implements Listener
{
    public DocumentListener(// a bunch of injected parameters) {

    }

    public abstract void receive(Event event);

}
```

Then I created Update

```java
public class DocumentUpdate extends DocumentListener
{
    // injected constructor

    @Override
    public void receive(Event event)
    {
    }
}
```

And

```java
public class DocumentDelete extends DocumentListener
{
    // injected constructor

    @Override
    public void receive(Event event)
    {
    }
}
```

Then Guice will complain with `1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]:` because now the DocumentListener is an abstract class which it doesn't know how to bind.

I could do something like this

```java
bind(DocumentListener.class).to(DocumentUpdate.class).in(SINGLETON);
```

But then I can only bind one class at a time. I can't bind two implementations as Guice will complain that the class is already binded and I can't bind twice.

Not sure if there's a pattern to solve this kind of problem with Guice and Listener pattern?

Comment: You could use a [multibinding](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Multibindings)

Answer (score 0):

If we have liberty to re-structure event itself we could implement it as below

```
interface Listener{}
enum Event{
    //avoid adding class variables which could induce state and thereby threadsafety concerns
    //add behaviour as 'method' and objects as 'method-param'
    UpdateEvent {
        @Override
        public void doDocumentListenerOperations(String phaseWhenReceive) {
            //update
        }
    },EntityDeleteEvent {
        @Override
        public void doDocumentListenerOperations(String phaseWhenReceive) {
            //delete
        }
    },PhaseEvent {
        @Override
        public void doDocumentListenerOperations(String phaseWhenReceive) {
            //no-op
        }
    };

    public abstract void doDocumentListenerOperations(String phaseWhenReceived);

}

public class DocumentListener implements Listener
{
    //@Inject
    public DocumentListener(){}// a bunch of injected parameters) {}

    public void receive(Event event)
    {
        //Phase phaseWhenReceived = phase_;
        event.doDocumentListenerOperations("phaseWhenReceived");//and other params required for executing the method
        
    }
}
```